# Parse a specific variable from a url stored as a string with CFML

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I want to parse a specific url variable key value from a url stored as a string. It seems that you can use the underlying java library coldfusion.util.HTMLTools under ACF, but I need it to work under Railo as well. Is there another way, or is using a regular expression the best answer?

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the url variable key without the anchor in a url formatted like the following example.
http://example.com?key=134324625625435#gid=0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was posting as a comment on Scott's answer, but it was getting too long, so...

John wrote:

> Running the following example I end up with the value of 0,
>   but I think it should be the entire key value?

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset theUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AthiZNZ73LBndUzRTUkplbmNhYWc##gid=0" />
    <cfset theUrl = listRest(theUrl, "?")>
    <cfloop list="#theUrl#" index="URLPiece" delimiters="&">
        Key: #listFirst(urlPiece, "=")# Value: #listLast(urlPiece, "=")# <br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

The reason for failure of that example URL is it contains a page segment (the bit after the hash), which needs to be stripped off before the query string can be parsed.

It's also important to get the correct variables/values by wrapping the key/value parts in `UrlDecode`.

Plus, it is perfectly acceptable to have an equal sign in the value, so `?key==` should return `=` as the value, which means changing the `ListLast` to a `ListRest` and setting `includeEmptyFields` to true.

Also, if you have a querystring such as `?a&b` then the convention is to set the value to either `true` or empty string - the current code is setting to the key name, which is wrong.

In summary, here's a function:

```
<cffunction name="getParamsFromUrlString" returntype="Struct" output=false >
    <cfargument name="UrlString" type="String" required />
    <cfargument name="Separator" type="String" default="?" />
    <cfargument name="Delimiter" type="String" default="&" />
    <cfargument name="AssignOp"  type="String" default="=" />
    <cfargument name="EmptyVars" type="String" default="" />

    <cfset var QueryString = ListRest( ListFirst( Arguments.UrlString , '##' ) , Arguments.Separator ) />
    <cfset var Result = {} />

    <cfloop index="local.QueryPiece" list=#QueryString# delimiters="#Arguments.Delimiter#">

        <cfif NOT find(Arguments.AssignOp,QueryPiece)>
            <cfset Result[ UrlDecode( QueryPiece ) ] = Arguments.EmptyVars />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset Result[ UrlDecode( ListFirst(QueryPiece,Arguments.AssignOp) ) ]
                =  UrlDecode( ListRest(QueryPiece,Arguments.AssignOp,true) ) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn Result />
</cffunction>
```

It can be used as simply as:

```
    <cfset theUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AthiZNZ73LBndUzRTUkplbmNhYWc##gid=0" />
    <cfset Data = getParamsFromUrlString( theUrl ) />
    <cfdump var=#Data# />
```

Or it can be used on complicated non-standard URL strings like this:

```
    <cfset theUrl = "https://somewhere/index.jsp;x:145;y:54;z:1;f;d:%23%23;w:%3B" />
    <cfset Data = getParamsFromUrlString( theUrl , ';' , ';' , ':' , 'true' ) />
    <cfdump var=#Data# />
```

And (hopefully) everything in between.

Answer (score 4):

Any variables that are passed as part of the query string are available in the URL scope - which is a 'built in' structure.

Here is some sample code that will out put those variables in your example:

```
<cfoutput>
    #url.id# <br />
    #url.key# <br />
    #url.output#
</cfoutput>
```

Adding to my answer to match new information and mbrusche's example:

```
<cfset urlString = listRest( urldata, "?" ) />
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#urlString#" index="URLPiece" delimiter="&">
        Key: #listFirst( urlPiece, "=" )# Value: #listLast( urlPiece, "=" (# <br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: In this case the url is being stored as a string in the database, so I need to parse it as a variable, not as part of the url scope.

Comment: Loop through the string using & as the delimiter. Then you can separate out the values from there.
`<cfloop list="#string#" index="urlpiece" delimiter="&">#urlpiece#</cfloop>`

Comment: Ahhh....I understand now. mbrusche's idea will work, but I think I would strip out the domain name and path first: string = listRest( string, "?") other wise the first iteration of the loop would contain the protocol, domain name, path & file. Inside that loop, you could then do listFirst( urlPiece, "=") to get the key and listLast( urlPiece, "=") to get the value.

Comment: I'm going to update my example as I think it my be misleading. In my actual url the key is the first url variable so I can't use the & as the delimiter.

Comment: Running the following example I end up with the value of 0, but I think it should be the entire key value?
<cfoutput>
<cfset theUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AthiZNZ73LBndUzRTUkplbmNhYWc##gid=0" />
<cfset theUrl = listRest(theUrl, "?")>
    <cfloop list="#theUrl#" index="URLPiece" delimiters="&">
        Key: #listFirst(urlPiece, "=")# Value: #listLast(urlPiece, "=")# <br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>

Comment: I ended up having to use the following to get the key value from my example url, based on input from Scott and mrbrusche. I did not need to loop as it appears the url's are consistent in that the key is the first variable followed by an anchor. I will need to loop if I find url's that contain more than one variable. 
<cfset theUrl = listFirst(ListRest(theUrl, "="), "##" )>

Comment: my .02 :)   If you have control over it, consider storing the variables as json instead of a query string.

Comment: Hi Mark, Just curious as to why that would be better? I'm sure I could pull the value from the database via a cfc with the result as json. Would this allow me to use a javascript function to pull the specific key value easily?

Comment: The benefit of JSON is that all modern CFML engines have `serializeJson` and `deserializeJson` methods built-in, so it's convenient if you need to store arbitrary data as a string.

Comment: However, in this instance you seem to be starting with a URL, so you'd still have to de-serialize the query string first, so there's no obvious benefit to JSON here (unless it makes sense for some other part of your application).

Answer (score 2):

Having just re-read the question, if you are only dealing with a single specific variable, you can easily do this with a simple regex:

```
<cfset Value = rematch( '[?&]key=[^&##]+' , TheUrl ) />
<cfset Value = UrlDecode( ListRest( Value[1] , '=' , true ) ) />
```

(The other answer is of course still useful if you need a more general purpose solution.)

Comment: I think the parameters of rematch() are the wrong way around (parameter ordering is rarely intuitive in CFML)

Comment: Well you're correct about the ordering (doh; fixed), but incorrect about rarely intuitive - it's not perfect, but it's not terrible either.

Comment: Perhaps "rarely intuitive" was a bit harsh, but it is at best inconsistent: 

Left(string, count),
Insert(substring, string, position),
REMatch(reg_expression, string),
REReplace(string, reg_expression, substring [, scope ])

Comment: Heh, go try PHP for a bit and you'll soon be yearning for just two variants to deal with. ;)

Comment: (But yes, the mismatch between rematch/refind and rereplace especially is one that very much [bugs me](http://cfregex.net/features.html#functions)!)