# GooglePlus Login with Coldfusion and URL contains #

Tags: url, authentication, parameters, coldfusion, google-plus

I am integrating GooglePlus login with Coldfusion however on redirect URL google send 
access_code with # instead of ? and coldfusion can't read url parameters with #. 
Any one can please help me

Request

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email%20profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost/view/login/googleplusReturned.cfm&response_type=token&client_id=XXXDUMY.apps.googleusercontent.com

Response

googleplusReturned.cfm#access_token=ya29.AAEmHefIfTUFjqLXsa3OMM92GciSZjj1Ds6b0OHwbLrv00fuFgxo1YZWFI4fmy9YXcWIJwOn_iP9xA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

Comment: You may be interested in this post by Peter Boughton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220795/parse-a-specific-variable-from-a-url-stored-as-a-string-with-cfml. Pass it the whole url, as well as proper values for delimiters and it should zip right through it.

Comment: Try this [blog entry](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/02/20/Google-SignIn-and-ColdFusion)

Comment: ColdFusion very much can read a URL parameter with a # in it. You only have to worry about # when you are creating a string and want to include the literal #.

Comment: Yes, like Ray says, you just need to use array notation. For a variable named `my.hash#tag` `#my.hash##tag#' won't work, but `#variables["myhash##tag"]#` will. Cold fusion can't understand that the first means one variable (since it's syntactically identical to two variables), but it parses the second syntax fine.

As far as I know, you can put nearly any character in cf variable name, but I think it's best to stick with alphanumeric, underscore and hyphen (tbh, I don't even use hyphen), but it's handy when you have an incoming variable with unusual names hee.